# Flag dialog claims I flagged a question or answer as VLQ when I didn't (raise a flag)

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, flag-dialog

When I open the flag dialogue on some posts I see the following:

[image: You have already raised a very low quality flag]

The flag dialogue claims that

> You have already raised a very low quality flag

When I haven't raised a flag, at all. Checking "Flags raised by..." in my profile confirms that I didn't actually raise a flag. It disappears if I raise another flag (eg. flag for closure or as NAA).

It's not easy to reproduce, likely only affects posts already flagged by someone else (thanks @10Rep for the [observation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52144845#52144845)). [Answers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/52144879#52144879) are also affected (as I could also observe myself later). This also means that I can't flag a post as VLQ.

Comment: See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364136/i-did-not-flag-all-these-posts-as-very-low-quality

Comment: This is a bug that was introduced when checking if you've already raised a flag - instead of looking at just your flags, it's looking at all flags. This is just a problem with the dialog check, there's not actually flags being raised on your behalf. I'm working on a fix now 

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This bug has now been fixed network wide. In a certain case of flagging logic, it was checking all flags instead of just your flags to see if you've already raised a flag. I've fixed the check and you should no longer see this issue anymore. Thanks for reporting, and let me know if you're still seeing it anywhere!